# sed replace quoted string with boolean?

Tags: regex, sed

I know this must be easy but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to replace

```
'2.0.0'
```

with

```
FALSE
```

I have

```
sed -i.bak s/"'\''2.0.0'\''"/"FALSE"/g config.php
```

I also tried...

```
sed -i.bak s/"'2.0.0'"/FALSE/g config.php
```

And pretty much every other single combination I could think of, them all do

```
'2.0.0' => 'FALSE'
```

How can I do it so it removes the single quotes?

Comment: That latter example `sed -i.bak s/"'2.0.0'"/FALSE/g config.php` should work. Are you sure it doesn't?

Comment: I'm 100% sure. If I run that on my Mac it replaces `'2.0.0'` with `'FALSE'`. `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: Did you try: `sed -i.bak "s/'2\.0\.0'/FALSE/g" config.php`?

Comment: That also doesn't "dequote it". Just replaces it.

Comment: Are you certain the input doesn't have `''2.0.0''` in it? Because that shouldn't be possible really.

Comment: This isn't a "dequoting" process. This is just replacement of a pattern that includes single quotes. `sed` can't really do anything else. If the pattern matches it gets replaced. If it doesn't match it doesn't get replaced.

Comment: Here is the file -https://gist.github.com/modernmediaca/e0fe8ca11ebd0b2043d9

Comment: If I run it on my Mac it works, if I run it on Ubuntu 14.04 it doesn't. Hrmmm....

Comment: I thought you said it didn't work on your Mac before?

Comment: I did, I am using vagrant so I forgot I was inside of the box ssh. I think it has something to do with using NTFS + sed + vagrant combination causing it to not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with `awk`

```
awk '{sub(q"2.0.0"q,"FALSE")}1' q="'" file
```

To write it back to the file:

```
awk '{sub(q"2.0.0"q,"FALSE")}1' q="'" file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: How do I write that too that file? This seems to work.

Comment: +1 for the use of a variable to avoid quoting/escaping madness.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (see but Jotne comment below):

`echo "'2.0.0'" | sed 's/.2\.0\.0./FALSE/'`

NOTE: A single dot . is a regexp for an arbitrary single character. Backslash an dot \. represent a literal dot.

EDIT: This combination of double and sigle quotes for sed's expression also work for me:

`echo "'2.0.0'" | sed "s/'2\.0\.0'/FALSE/"`

Comment: Problem with this, is that it will also replace `k2a0t0f`

Comment: Partially true. It will replace <code>k2.0.0f</code>, but not   <code>k2a0t0f</code> because <code>\\.</code> match a literal dot.

Comment: Did not see the `\` before the dot, but still it may in some case replace wrong parts.